# Connecting UCM with Apache server on another machine

Tags: apache, tomcat, oracle-ucm

I am trying to connect to my content server(UCM) using apache server installed in another machine. 
In more short notation ,i want to use apache server of another machine to login to my system's content server (UCM)
Any kind of help would be of great use

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer and I thought it would be nice to tell this to others too,
so I found the following link
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e12037/contentsvr.htm#BGBDDCFF

Here in section 9.4 , you can go through what is to be done.
For avoiding confusion, in this section WCHOST is local machine and WEBHOST is remote one.

Thanks